# Shrinking Button Affects other elements

Tags: html, css, padding

I added the active pseudo class to my HTML buttons and i want them to shrink when they are clicked... the problem is they affect every element on the page with the shrinking. I only want the button to shrink and every element should stay still during ...

These are my buttons :

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button id="btn-start" class="btn">Start</button>
  <button id="btn-stop" class="btn">Stop</button>
  <button id="btn-reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
</div>
```

The basic styling of them:

```css
.btn-container .btn{
    background: #fe2f6d;
    border: none ;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: x-large;
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

And the active pseudo:

```css
.btn:active{
   padding: 18px 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the CSS [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) property here instead of changing the padding:

```css
.btn-container .btn {
  background: #fe2f6d;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  margin: 0px 0 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: x-large;
  border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button id="btn-start" class="btn">Start</button>
  <button id="btn-stop" class="btn">Stop</button>
  <button id="btn-reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
</div>
```